# Unity3d. Android. AdMob

Tags: android, unity3d, admob

Прикручиваю AdMob к приложению, сделанному на Unity3d 5 для Android. Приложение собирается и работает, но как только доходит до вызова `bannerView.LoadAd(request);` приложение крашится. Вроде всё не сложно, и даже сверялся с этим [видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RBUxmOTY3Ng). В принципе, отсебятины там мало. Кто-нибудь сталкивался? Возможно есть какие-то тонкости, но там всё на английском. А он у меня плоховат.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using GoogleMobileAds;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
public class exitForApp : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    public void market () {
        RequestBanner();
    }



    private void RequestBanner()
    {   
        #if UNITY_ANDROID
        string adUnitId = "ca-app-pub-6464195660187466/777777777";
        #elif UNITY_IPHONE
        string adUnitId = "INSERT_IOS_BANNER_AD_UNIT_ID_HERE";
        #else
        string adUnitId = "unexpected_platform";
        #endif

        // Create a 320x50 banner at the top of the screen.
        BannerView bannerView = new BannerView(adUnitId, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Top);
        // Create an empty ad request.
        AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
        // Load the banner with the request.
        bannerView.LoadAd(request);
    }   
}
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This Google Mobile Ads plugin library manifest will get merged with your
application's manifest, adding the necessary activity and permissions
required for displaying ads.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.unity"
    android:versionName="1.0"
    android:versionCode="1">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9"
      android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
  <!-- Google Mobile Ads Permissions -->
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
  <!-- Uncomment to add billing for in-app purchase ads -->
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
  <application>
    <!-- Denote the referenced Google Play services version -->
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    <!-- Google Mobile Ads Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    <!-- InAppPurchase Activity -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.purchase.InAppPurchaseActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.IAPTheme"/>

<activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
    <intent-filter>
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
      <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik"
        android:value="true" />
</activity>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Без лога краша почти невозможно вам помочь. А раз вы его не приложили, то, видать, там `NPE` какое-нибудь.

Comment: Посмотрите вот здесь. Может речь не о том, но все работает.
http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/85299/

Comment: Здесь пишут, ссылка не катит.Могут удалить ответ. На этот случай - речь идет о :"Добавление рекламы AdMob в Android-приложение".Если это то что нужно, скажите куда, я перешлю плагин.

Comment: @Georgich: удалять не будем, просто преобразуем в комментарий. Ссылку он отлично хранит. А в ответе действительно должна быть не только ссылка — ссылки часто протухают, да и SO это сборник решений, а не ссылок )

Comment: @Georgich: Будет здорово, если вы опубликуете более подробный ответ. )

Answer (score -3):

нужно завести аккаунд AdMob;
После процедуры регистрации нам нужно монетизировать новое приложение.
Следующим шагом будет создание рекламного блока.
Создаём баннер с частотой обновления 60 секунд.
После создания баннера мы получаем идентификатор рекламного блока в формате: ca-app-pub-ххххххххххххххх/хххххххххх, этот идентификатор и является привязкой нашего рекламного блока в приложении с сервисом Admob.
Скачиваем под нашу версию Unity плагин для Unity3D, отсюда: https://github.com/guillermocalvo/admob-unity-plugin/tree/master/Releases.
Теперь переходим в Unity и переносим в него наш плагин, который скачали с GitHub (Assets -> Import Package -> Custom Package) и получаем все необходимые файлы. Плагин уже готов к работе посредством префаба, который нужно просто перенести на сцену, в которой будет отображаться реклама.В префабе находится 3 скрипта, каждый отвечает за свою роль:
1) Ad Mob Plugin — главный скрипт, который и выдаёт нашу рекламу.
2) Ad Mob Plugin Debug — дополнительный скрипт, который показывает кнопки, с помощью которых можно менять положение / вид / размер баннера в приложении.
3) Ad Mob Plugin Mockup — макет баннера. Используется для теста рекламного блока на сцене.
Последние два скрипта используются для тестирования, их нужно обязательно отключить перед билдом игры. 
 Несколько главных полей в этом скрипте:
Publisher ID — это и есть тот самый идентификатор рекламного блока, который мы получили в Admob (ca-app-pub-ххххххххххххххх/хххххххххх). Соответственно вводим его в это поле.
Refresh Interval — частота обновления рекламного блока, ставим то же значения, что указали в Admob (60 сек.).
Основные моменты: Перед билдом отключаем Is Testing в Ad Mob Plugin, отключаем в префабе Ad Mob Plugin Debug и Ad Mob Plugin Mockup, вписываем наш Идентификатор рекламного блока в Publisher ID. В сцене с рекламой один префаб Admob Plugin.
Статья взята отсюда http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/85299/, спасибо человеку.